KNN typeerror and data normalization
I can't get the predict working even while doing everything a tutorial indicate.
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

knn_model = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3, metric='euclidean')
knn_model.fit(train_val_process, merge_labels.label)
y_pred_knn = knn.predict(test_data_process)

The error is the following :
TypeError: KNeighborsClassifier.predict() missing 1 required positional argument: 
'X'

I'm supposed to normalize the data mean 1 std 0. Is it good ?
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(pd.concat([train_data, val_data]))
train_data_process = pd.DataFrame(scaler.transform(train_data), columns=train_data.columns)
val_data_process = pd.DataFrame(scaler.transform(val_data), columns=val_data.columns)
train_val_process = pd.concat([train_data, val_data])
test_data_process = pd.DataFrame(scaler.transform(test_data), columns=test_data.columns)
y_test = test_labels.label


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Your model is called knn_model, not knn, so it should be knn_model.predict and not knn.predict (typo).

The issue comes from your variables names.
You are calling knn, which hasn't been declared/trained. Instead, you trained knn_model.
Update to the following :
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

knn_model = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3, metric='euclidean')
knn_model.fit(train_val_process, merge_labels.label)
y_pred_knn = knn_model.predict(test_data_process)

Then, you can proceed to test your model comparing y_pred_knn with the test labels and compute accuracy, recall...
To the best of my knowledge, your standardization method has a mistake. Again, you seems to be calling the wrong variables.
While doing :
train_val_process = pd.concat([train_data, val_data])

You are using the non standardized data, so your scaler seems useless.
I would recommend following a simple tutorial about standardization to correct this mistake.
